# C Program :Error when reading character from stdin using scanf

Tags: c

Currently im trying to learn simple C Programs. But, i came into this situation :

```
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdio.h>

void main()
{
   char c;
   int tryagain=1;

   while(tryagain>0){
       printf("Enter the Character : ");
   scanf("%c",&c);
       printf("You entered the character \"%c\" and the ascii value is %d",c,c);

    getch();
    clrscr();
    tryagain=0;

    printf("You want to Trry again Press 1 : ");
    scanf("%d",&tryagain);
    clrscr();

    }
 }
```

The program is fine when user first enter a character. And, when it ask to continue. And, user enter 1 then it is behaving weired. It automatically input blank character and prints the ascii and goto the same place.

How can i resolve this? And, specially, Why is the reason for this?

And, Im sorry about my poor english!

Thank you in Advance.

Comment: `scanf("%d",&tryagain);` remain newline.

Comment: Im sorry i dont understood. Im very basic user. Please tell me more about why and how i resolve.

Comment: try change `scanf("%d",&tryagain);` to `scanf("%d%*c",&tryagain);`

Comment: `scanf("%d",&tryagain);` : `1` enter then `%d` consume `1` and remain newline. `%*c` consume 1 char('\n').

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you are reading a single number in the second scanf, but user inputs more than a single number there, the user also input a new line character by pressing .

User enters "1\n". Your scanf reads "1", leaving out "\n" in the input stream. Then the next scanf that reads a character reads "\n" from the stream.

Here is the corrected code. I use getc to discard the extra new line character that is there.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
    char c;
    int tryagain = 1;

    while (tryagain > 0) {
        printf("Enter a character: ");
        scanf("%c", &c);
        printf("You entered the character \"%c\" and the ascii value is %d\n", c, c);

        tryagain = 0;

        printf("If you want to try again, enter 1: ");
        scanf("%d", &tryagain);
        // get rid of the extra new line character
        getc(stdin);
    }
}
```

---

Also, as a side note, you use `conio.h` which is not part of standard C, it's MS-DOS header file, thus it's not portable C you are writing. I have removed it from my code, but you might wish to keep it.

Comment: Using `fflush(stdin)` [is discouraged](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979209/using-fflushstdin).

Comment: Okey. Thank you so much John. You given me the detailed info so, im going to accept your answer. Thank you again.

Answer (score 4):

When you use

```
scanf("%d",&tryagain);
```

the number is read into `tryagain` but the newline character, `'\n'`, is still left on the input stream. The next time you use:

```
scanf("%c",&c);
```

the newline character is read into the `c`.

By using

```
scanf("%d%*c",&tryagain);
```

the newline is read from the input stream but it is not stored anywhere. It is simply discarded.